# How can I clean my stainless steel teapot?

Tags: cleaning

I have a rather nice stainless steel teapot that I use every day.  I've started to get some black buildup due to using it on a gas range.  What method would work well for restoring my teapot back to its original condition?

Answer (score 3):

There's a cleanser product called Barkeeper's Friend that is great for stuff like this. http://www.barkeepersfriend.com/

Comment: If you are not in the US, the active ingredient in BKF is oxalic acid IIRC, so any product based on it should perform similarly.